# iphone-loading sound files quickly

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, crash, xcode5

I have a space shooter game I am making. I want to play a sound every time a user hits the button fire. This is a short .wav file of about half a second in length. Also, when the user dies, I have an explosion .mp3 file to play. Since the fire button can be clicked very rapidly, I need to play sounds quickly. I used some avaudio player code previously where I make a new audioplayer every time I need to fire, but this crashes occasionally if I fire very quickly. Any suggestions on ways to play sound files very quickly? (including some example code in you answer would be great)

Answer (score 0):

if you using MPMediaPlayback you can try [prepareToPlay](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MPMediaPlayback/prepareToPlay)

Comment: However, when I click the fire button very rapidly, will it play the full duration of the sound before it plays the next one, or will it cut the sound from the first fire off when I click fire the second time?